# ASP.NET Identity - AuthenticationManager.SignOut not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, claims

I am trying to logout my users when a JWT token is expired. But for some reason, the ClaimsPrincipal still exists after I Signout.

For eg: Request.IsAuthenticated is always true even after I singed out.

I am signing out of all the available authentication types. (ApplicationCookie, ExternalCookie, Auth0).

I am not sure what I might be missing here.

```
 internal static void SignOut()
    {
        var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        if (authenticationManager == null) return;
        var appTypes = authenticationManager.GetAuthenticationTypes().Select(at => at.AuthenticationType).ToArray();
        authenticationManager.SignOut(appTypes);

        var httpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        httpResponse.Redirect(
            string.Format("https://{0}/logout?returnTo={1}",
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0Domain"],
                 httpRequest.Url));
    }
```

I appreciate any suggestions / thoughts that might guide me in the direction to resolve this issue.

Comment: Not sure which identityserver you're using, but here is a guide from Identityserver https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html. See 'Adding Logout'

Comment: Show the code in `Startup.Auth.cs`?

Comment: @trailmax Thanks for your time. I was calling the Signout() from the 'ActionFilter' and action method continued to execute even after calling the Signout. I solved the issue by Signing out the session and then set 'filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult('logouturl)' in the filter. That way it stopped the execution of the Action method and logged out the user properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time. I was calling the Signout() from the 'ActionFilter' and action method continued to execute even after calling the Signout. I solved the issue by Signing out the session and then set

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult('logouturl)
```

in the filter. That way it stopped the execution of the Action method and logged out the user properly